# Getting node value from XML

Tags: python, xml

I am getting the response in XML from a request which i need to parse and find the specfic node value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<statusCode>200</statusCode>
<statusText>Ok</statusText>
<data>
<testId>161115_16_J1G</testId>
<ownerKey></ownerKey>
<xmlUrl>http://www.webpagetest.org/xmlResult/161115_16_J1G/</xmlUrl>
<userUrl>http://www.webpagetest.org/result/161115_16_J1G/</userUrl>
<summaryCSV>http://www.webpagetest.org/result/161115_16_J1G/page_data.csv
</summaryCSV>
<detailCSV>http://www.webpagetest.org/result/161115_16_J1G/requests.csv
</detailCSV>

</data>
</response>
response=urllib2.urlopen("url")
 print(response)
 xml=ET.fromstring(response)
 root = xml.getroot()
 for child in root:
 print child.tag, child.attrib
 output
```

statuscode :200
statustetxt:ok
data:\n
not getting the rest of the value

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the relevant part of the XML and the Python code you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: Which "specific" node do you want to access?

Comment: i need to  access all the inner node of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
child=tree.findall("/data/")
for x in child:
  print x.tag,x.text
```

it worked for me

Comment: one more way of doing is this using t=tree.getchildren() by this also one can all the nodes